# How to use a catch-phrase for a validated result when presented before an examining committee?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, catch-phrases

Imagine, that someone is preparing for a PhD defense. The thesis that he is going to defend is by far against the norm. That is, it uncovers deep-seated beliefs that led to 30 years of malpractice. So he knew in advance that if he will not be well prepared for that this would label his thesis a *heresy*. Therefore, he did his best to analyze the data at hand very carefully, doing everything possible to validate the results and justify his approach why this method and not that sort of thing. He adopted a very hard and long path just to be well prepared for the day of defense. In addition, he knew in advance that the examiners will be not that easy to convince unless a really solid proof is presented before their eyes.

I want to describe the results of the PhD student using a catch-phrase:
One phrase came to my mind, but I am not sure how suitable it is here:

> The results concluded form the analysis were *irrefutable*.

Please, can you help me with better phrases or iterations of the same theme, e.g., using the committee-[something], I heard of one phrase but I lost the site where I read it, it was like: jury-[something]. Now looking for it like searching for a straw in a haystack.

Comment: It might have been a nonce word such as [jury-swaying](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all#hl=all&q=%22jury-swaying%22). 'Committee-swaying' would be noncer (but probably less so than 'noncer').

Comment: thanks, I don't know if this is the word, but does it suggest also that the concluded results are *immune* to critics made by the jury? they cannot refute it or contradict it.

Comment: No. Without going too deeply into analysing the validity of the underlying assumption that people are inherently persuadable by sound argument ('some people can't see past the nose on their face' and 'you can fool some of the people all of the time'), if you want a word that means 'incontestable', 'incontrovertible', 'conclusive', I'd say you've picked the best with 'irrefutable'.

Comment: Something is confusing me here. Your first paragraph builds up the story that the candidate is *expecting* and preparing for a major academic battle. Then you ask about the phrase used to describe the case that he has already *won* the battle (swayed the committee). Are you seeking a phrase he should use (to sway the committee), or what?

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply seeking a correct version of

> The results concluded form the analysis were irrefutable.

Then any of these would suffice:

> The results of the analysis were irrefutable.
>
> The results from the analysis were irrefutable.
>
> The conclusions of the analysis were irrefutable.
>
> The conclusions from the analysis were irrefutable.

As Edwin suggests, 'incontestable' or 'incontrovertible' could work instead of 'irrefutable', but so might 'indisputable',  'undeniable', 'beyond dispute', 'unassailable' or 'unquestionable'.